# Autocad API, Databinding Inotifyproperty change not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am trying from several days to try to make it work but I could not.. Please help.

My xaml

> ```
>          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
>          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SchneiderMacros"
>          mc:Ignorable="d" 
>          d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
> <UserControl.DataContext >
>     <local:mainviewmodel ></local:mainviewmodel> 
> </UserControl.DataContext>
> <Grid Background="#FF2D2D30">
>     <StackPanel >
>         <TextBox Height=" 30" Text="{Binding device}" Margin=" 10"></TextBox>
>
>     </StackPanel>
>
> </Grid> </UserControl>
> ```

My view class

> Public Class PNWPFPalette
>
> ```
> Public devicelocaton As String
> Shared _PS1 As PaletteSet = Nothing
> Public Sub ShowPNWPFPalette()
>
>     If _PS1 Is Nothing Then
>         _PS1 = New PaletteSet("Modify Attributes")
>         _PS1.Size = New Size(400, 600)
>         _PS1.DockEnabled = DirectCast(CInt(DockSides.Left) + CInt(DockSides.Right), DockSides)
>         Dim uc1 As New PN_NO
>         '_PS1.AddVisual("Update PN", uc1)
>         Dim host As ElementHost = New ElementHost
>         host.AutoSize = True
>         host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
>         host.Child = uc1
>         _PS1.Add("Modify PN", host)
>         Dim uc2 As New PN_NO
>         Dim host1 As ElementHost = New ElementHost
>         host1.AutoSize = True
>         host1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
>         host1.Child = uc2
>         _PS1.Add("Modify PN2", host1)
>     End If
>     _PS1.KeepFocus = True
>     _PS1.Visible = True
> End Sub
>
>
> Public Function findattributes()
>     Dim DL As String= "Pankaj"
>
>     Return DL
> End Function
> ```
>
> End Class

My Viewmodel class

> Public Class mainviewmodel
>       Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
>
> ```
> Public Property device As String
>     Get
>         Return _device
>     End Get
>     Set(value As String)
>         _device = value
>         OnPropertyChange("device")
>     End Set
> End Property
> Private _device As String
> Protected Sub OnPropertyChange(name As String)
>     RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
> End Sub
> Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
> ```
>
> End Class

Command class

> Public Class commands  
>   Public Sub PNPalette()
>   Dim addpn As New PNWPFPalette
>   Dim viewmodel As New mainviewmodel
>   addpn.ShowPNWPFPalette()
>   Dim DL As String = addpn.findattributes()
>   viewmodel.device = DL
>   End Sub
>
> End Class

Afte running command textbox remains blank... Please help.......

Comment: I replied you in your duplicated post: 
http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/autocad-api-data-bindinding-does-not-work/m-p/6225249#M47940

Comment: @gileCAD, thanks Man, but can you please tell me what I need to edit? Do I need to remove <usercontrol.datacontext> code from Xaml?